# Optimize Chapter Styling

Tags: chapters, double-sided, books

Im currently writing my thesis and use a premade template to style my chapter headings (Modified nr 26 at http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html, credit to Vincent Zoonekynd).

I am pretty much satisfyed with the result, but I want to reduce the vertical space between the first chapter name and the second for every new chapter, e.g. reduce/ remove the vertical space between "Chapter 1" and "Introduction".

Could anyone help?
Some of my code is included below (too much to include all):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fourier}        
\usepackage{lipsum}     
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}       % style paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0}       % style paragraphs
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-10\p@}                          % Distance top(?)
      {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-30\p@}                        % Distance to line(?)
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 50\p@                            % Distance to text(?)
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
       \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    %\vspace*{1\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to put in a negative space (`\vspace{-6pt}`) at two places in the code. Instead of  `6pt`you can use `0.5\baselineskip` or perhaps the value `{-10\p@}`, in case you later change the font size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fourier}            % Not necessary for the MWE to compile
\usepackage{lipsum}     
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}       % style paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}       % style paragraphs. Added `em` to avoid error
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-10\p@}                          % Distance top(?)
      {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\vspace*{-10\p@}%      %Reduce the distance between chapter number and chapter title
        \nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-30\p@}                        % Distance to line(?)
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 50\p@                            % Distance to text(?)
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
        \par\vspace*{-10\p@}%      %Reduce the distance between chapter number and chapter title
        \nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-30\p@}%           % uncommented and change to `-30\p@` for consistency
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 50\p@%               % change from 100\p@ for consistency
  }}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

You have inconsistent space two other places, which I have corrected.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! It did solve the problem :) As far as I can see, I didn't have to remove the fourier package to make it work. May this cause problems later on?

Comment: @user106025 No, the fourier package was only a problem for me, because I had not installed the package on my system. I will remove that comment in the MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, both for numbered and unnumbered chapters.  Note the weird discrepancy for the vertical distance between chapter titles and text  in both cases. Is this wanted?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}       % style paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}       % style paragraphs
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-10\p@}                          % Distance top(?)
      {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter \vspace*{-10\p@}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-30\p@}                        % Distance to line(?)
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 50\p@                            % Distance to text(?)
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}\vspace*{\dimexpr -10pt - 1.57ex \relax}
       \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-30\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter*{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! No, the discrepancy was just an(other) mistake I made when writing the question :)